# "Wrong Data Type" error for setting cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm starting to use vba (for excel) for the first time (I've plenty of experience in other languages) and got stuck with this:

```
Function SetCellValue()
 Dim cellRange As Range
 Set cellRange = Range("D35")
 cellRange.Value = 8
End Function
```

(This is a simplified version of what I'm actaully trying to do). If I debug this in the vba editor it all works as expected, and the value 8 appears in the correct cell. But if I enter

```
=SetCellValue()
```

into a cell in the spreadsheet itself, I get the error "a value used in the formula is of the wrong data type".

If I do this instead

```
Function SetCellValue()
 Dim cellRange As Range
 Set cellRange = Range("D35")
 SetCellValue = 8
End Function
```

then the spreadsheet works as expected. So what value is 'the wrong data type' in the first example?

Comment: Don't use a `Function` for this... Functions are supposed to return something, you are coding a procedure into a function.

Comment: More as a general comment: UDFs can't (except for some edge cases) modify the sheet. Remove the `Dim` and `Set` lines from the second example - they are superfluous. If you're trying to modify the sheet, use a `Sub`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the duplicate. I did try to find similar threads. Didn't know the UDF acronym. Made it into a macro now but having problems with security! Another question beckons.